# text into xml page

Tags: php, sql

I need to put some text after `105` and I'm out of this. If you're know how to do it help me please.

```
 elseif($h=="105"){
            echo '<dst name="'.$h.'" '.($count['callcenter'] ? 'callcenter="'.$count['callcenter'].'"' : "").' good="'.$count['good'].'" bad="'.$count['bad'].'"></dst>';
            }
```

Comment: Where is the if for this?? And what text you want to add??

Comment: if is doing well, i just cant make some space for text that's all. So many ' and "" make me angry and i'm learning php two or three days.

Comment: put your string in `htmlentities("tags stuff")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate any string like this:

```
    if($h=="105")
   {
     $append = $count['callcenter'] ? 'callcenter="'.$count['callcenter'].'"' : "";
     echo '<dst name="'.$h.$append.'" good="'.$count['good'].'" bad="'.$count['bad'].'"></dst>';
   }
```

Comment: `<dst name="105" good="97" bad="264"/>`
this is my current output and I'm looking for something like this
`<dst name="105 Number_Text" good="97" bad="264"/>`
may you help me?

Comment: So what you actually want to do?

Comment: thanks a lot. Now i get it. You're my personal Jesus

Answer (score 0):

Above if, assign the value for `$var`;

```
 $var = "";//assign what you want here.
 if() { }
 elseif($h=="105$var"){
     echo '<dst name="'.$h.'" '.($count['callcenter'] ? 'callcenter="'.$count['callcenter'].'"' : "").' good="'.$count['good'].'" bad="'.$count['bad'].'"></dst>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be mixed with quotes

```
 elseif($h=="105")
      echo '<dst name="'.$h.'" '.($count['callcenter'] ? 'callcenter="'.$count['callcenter'].'"' : '').' good="'.$count['good'].'" bad="'.$count['bad'].'"></dst>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlentities("xml or html string here ...")` It will return what you want

```
elseif ($h == "500") {
    echo htmlentities('<dst name="'.$h.'" '.($count['callcenter'] ? 'callcenter="'.$count['callcenter'].'"' : "").' good="'.$count['good'].'" bad="'.$count['bad'].'"></dst>');
}
```